# Just how limited should the responsibilities of a Repository be?

Tags: oop, architecture, domain-driven-design, data-access-layer

Some reading tells me my Repositories(1) should do nothing at all but direct CRUD operations through the configured (injected) data provider, but very often in small projects I find adding a whole service layer as well to be a bit much.

Example, my app deals with 'bank' branches and clients. Now, if my user 'opens' a branch for each work session, and each new client is assigned to that branch, I feel inclined to inject an AppContext singleton I've written, to track ambient app attribiutes such as the currently opened branch, into my ClientRepository and let that object assign the correct BranchID to the new client record.

I know this is not correct in the purest sense, but I am talking basic 2 tiers apps here, UI and data. The only business 'logic' is really done in querying the database. Are there any more suitable patterns I could be using here?

(1) [The Repository Pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html)

Comment: Exceptionally vague, I couldn't understand anything. What is your system (language, libraries, basic concepts of operation)? What are the "repositories" and "branches" in your case? This should shed some light on the meaning of the identifiers too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally agree that the Repository should be as "clean" as possible like you described in the first paragraph.

From experience, I have "cheated" by also writing business logic code in the CRUD functions, which often required other repositories to be properties.

Working in ASP.net, I took advantage of generics and event-handling.

```
public class Repository<T, DC>
        where T : class
        where DC : DataContext, new()
{
    public delegate void RecordInsertedHandler(object s, BasicEventArgs<T> e);
    public event RecordInsertedHandler RecordInserted;

    public delegate void RecordDeletedHandler(object s, BasicEventArgs<T> e);
    public event RecordDeletedHandler RecordDeleted;

    public delegate void RecordObtainedHandler(object s, BasicEventArgs<T> e);
    public event RecordObtainedHandler RecordObtained;

    public delegate void RecordUpdatedHandler(object s, BasicEventArgs<T> e);
    public event RecordUpdatedHandler RecordUpdated;

    protected DC dc;

    public Repository(string connectionString="")
    {
        dc = ((connectionString == null) || (connectionString == "")) ? new DC() :   DynamicTypes.Instantiate<DC>(connectionString);  // See code below for DynamicTypes:

    }

    // There are similar functions for other events not shown.
    protected void OnRecordInserted(BasicEventArgs<T> obj)
    {
        if (RecordInserted != null)
        {
            RecordInserted(this, obj);
        }
    }

    // Only the Insert is shown here.
    private void Insert(T obj)
    {
        dc.GetTable<T>().InsertOnSubmit(obj);
        dc.SubmitChanges();

        OnRecordInserted(new BasicEventArgs<T>(obj));
    }
}
```

The basic idea is that you would fire/invoke these events in the correct places of your regular CRUD functions. I presume that your repository will be a member of an ASP.net page or a Windows form. Those containers then would be the "event listeners" since they can manipulate the UI.

Dynamic Types:

```
public static class DynamicTypes
{        
    public static T Instantiate<T>(params object[] args)
    {
        return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), args);
    }
}
```

BasicEventArgs:

```
public class BasicEventArgs<T> : EventArgs
{
    private T _Data;
    private string _Message;

    public BasicEventArgs(T data, string message="") : base()
    {
        _Data = data;
        _Message = message;
    }

    public T Data
    {
        get { return _Data; }
        set { _Data = value; }
    }

    public string Message
    {
        get { return _Message; }
        set { _Message = value; }
    }
}
```

Repositories:

```
public class BranceshRepository : Repository<Branch, YourDataContext>
{
     public BranchesRepository(string connectionString="") : base(connectionString)
     {
     }
}

public class ClientsRepository : Repository<Client, YourDataContext>
{
     public ClientsRepository(string connectionString="") : base(connectionString)
     {
     }
}
```

Now, for example, we have an ASP.net page:

```
public partial class MyPage : Page
{
      protected ClientsRepository _ClientsRepository;
      protected BranchesRepository _BranchesRepository;

      protected void Page_Load(object s, EventArgs e);
      {
           _ClientsRepository = new ClientsRepository(...);
           _BranchesRepository = new BranchesRepository(...);

           _BranchesRepository.RecordInserted += new Repository<Branch,YourDataContext>.RecordInsertedHandler(OnBranchInserted);
           _ClientsRepository.RecordInserted += new RepositoryM<Client, YourDataContext>.RecordInsertedHandler(OnClientInserted);
      }

      protected void OnBranchInserted(object s, BasicEventArgs<Branch> e)
      {
             /* e.Data is your newly-inserted branch with the newly-generated Id
                from the database. You may save this branch to Session for
                later use when your user inserts a new client.
               */
      }

      protected void OnClientInserted(object s, BasicEventArgs<Client> e)
      {
              Branch currentBranch = (Branch)Session["Branch"];
              e.Data.BranchId = currentBranch.Id;
              _ClientsRepository.Update(e.Data);                
      }

      // Control event handlers not shown, like CreateClient_BT_Click, for example.
}
```

This way, you do not need to inject a singleton in your ClientsRepository, and you have full access to your UI in these event handlers.

Answer (score 1):

In our team we are pursuing (for about 3 or 4 years at least) this perfect world idea, that all business logic must be totally removed from business logic. So we build a lot of services.

We believe, that in this perfect world that if you have a specific scope, you create a service for it. As Mickael previously mentioned "ClientsRepository" would provide SCRUD (s - search) for Clients, only we call it ClientsService (as in Service that tells you everything about clients). Here you have threat, that when an uninformed developer or one under extreme pressure or deadlines sees a code like this:

```
public ModifyClientResponse ModifyClient(ModifyClientRequest request){

    ClientEntity clientEntity=new ClientEntity();
    ModifyClientResponse clientResponse = new ModifyClientResponse();

    ClientMapper mapper=new ClientMapper();
    mapper.Map(request.Client, clientEntity);

    clientEntity.Update();

    ClientDTO responseClientDto=new ClientDTO();
    mapper.Map(clientEntity, responseClient);

    clientResponse.Client=responseClientDto;

    return clientResponse
}
```

Which is, I think, pretty straightforward. And that same developer gets a task, to do something like "when the clients shipping address is updated, we need to change his address data in the invoices that are not yet approved or shipped", it will become something like this:

```
public ModifyClientResponse ModifyClient(ModifyClientRequest request){

    ClientEntity clientEntity=new ClientEntity();
    ModifyClientResponse clientResponse = new ModifyClientResponse();

    ClientMapper mapper=new ClientMapper();
    mapper.Map(request.Client, clientEntity);

    clientEntity.Update();

    if(clientEntity.Address.DataModification==DataModification.Modified){
    // all the silly business logics about address being changed
    }

    ClientDTO responseClientDto=new ClientDTO();
    mapper.Map(clientEntity, responseClient);

    clientResponse.Client=responseClientDto;

    return clientResponse
}
```

Now no one is blaming that developer and in the small scale that is efficient enough and good enough. But in the long run it will become a disaster. The always changin requirements will be harder and harder to maintain and basically we think that it is against SOA and most of the SOLID development principles. It diminishes the services single responsibility - all kinds of bad stuff.

Yet, I would like to come back to that, that this should happen in the "perfect world": the above code at our place is handled by firing a message with the Clients DTO for anyone to handle. So Invoice service can hook up to "Client Modify" and using a handler, do the adequate processing. This way we keep our clients decoupled - they can be in another data source/server/planet/whatever if needed.

We also try to keep this even more clean, without the custom message handlers, but with workflows. We have an inhouse workflow engine (pretty much something like windows workflow foundation or jboss) which can subscribe and trigger workflows depending on some events.

Currently we are investigating a creation of ECA rules engine (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_condition_action), that would make this even more flexible. But enough about us :)

Your task would, if I was to implement it, would be a service which does only (s)CRUD and fires messages and another service that handles those messages and performs business logics. But that would be the perfect world approach, probably the estimate for that would scare someone up the ladder. And I would do this in the simplest possible way, i.e. by coupling everything together, yet sutaining the basic principles of good code, just for it to be less painful if this system suddenly grew up to a large-scale product of opening and closing bank branches.

In short: I aggree, repositories should be crystal clear, there shouldn't be anything but the data.